# how to omit double quotes and array brackets from a string in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a string in the format ["gated","gas"] i want this to be in the format as : gated,gas.

for this i have used str_replace function and i also get the required output but i want some alternate to do this task.

```
$newArray['Ameneties'] = ["gated","gas"] this is a string not an array
$a = str_replace('"', '',$newArray['Ameneties']);
$b = str_replace('[', '',$a);
$c = str_replace(']', '', $b);
echo $c;
```

i got the right output but i think there should be correct way of doing this as i have used the str_replace multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way is to `json_decode` and `implode`

```
echo implode( ",", json_decode( '["gated","gas"]' ));
```

This will return to:

```
gated,gas
```

Comment: @PandatArun Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can replace string more than 1,

```
$string = str_replace(array('[', '"', ']'), '', '["gated","gas"]');
echo $string; // Output: gated,gas
```

Docs : [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)